# Model box cannot open in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Modal = () => {
  const modalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    modals.forEach((modal) => {
      modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', () => {
        const easein = modal.getAttribute('data-easein');
        const modalDialog = modal.querySelector('.modal-dialog');

        if (easein === 'swing') {
          modalDialog.classList.add('callout', 'swing');
        } else {
          modalDialog.classList.add('transition', easein);
        }
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <a href="#customModal29" role="button" className="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">
        swing
      </a>

      <div
        ref={modalRef}
        id="customModal29"
        className="modal"
        data-easein="swing"
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="customModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
              </button>
              <h4 className="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
                ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                Close
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

When is click on swing the model box cannot appear.

Comment: <a href="#costumModal29" role="button" className="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">
        swing
      </a>

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, you are using native code with ReactJS, which is not best practice for using ReactJS in general.

The benefit of using ReactJS to manage and simplify your code is that it can be controlled.

I suggest you use a component like [Modal] [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) to be able to manage your component by react state, which is useful in your scenario.